# Audio or Video Priority Constraints in vLine (WebRTC)

Tags: webrtc, vline

As I am developing a video chat application based on the vLine API (fantastic so far), I deal with a lot of high latency and lower bandwidth connections.

I know that a lot of this is abstracted to the browser doing the work behind the scenes, but I am trying to find out if one is able to prioritize audio over video, in regards to quality and bandwidth.

It's always better to be able to hear someone even if the video becomes poor. Are there any abilities to do this in WebRTC and vLine in particular? Ideally, I would like to implement a slider control or checkbox with pre-defined constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to prioritize audio over video via constraints in a video call. The browser will try to do the 'right thing' in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I kind of thought that was the answer, but I wanted to ask the experts!

Comment: it's been so many years since this question was answered.  Is there a way now to prioritize Audio over Video. I found "priority" property in RTCRtpSendParameters but couldn't get much info yet.