# How to set priority to Audio over Video in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

Is there a way to set higher priority to Audio over video in WebRTC?

I am working on Cordova based mobile App and it uses Chrome Web View. My requirement is that Audio quality should not degrade in case of low bandwidth. Currently, I observed that Video and Audio both freezes or sometimes audio is not played at receiver side when running on low bandwidth.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888549/audio-or-video-priority-constraints-in-vline-webrtc) question but no solution provided there.

I also found a "[priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/setParameters)" param in RTCRtpSender. But not sure about it.

I also found a long discussion about QoS priority [here](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/1625) but I am still out of solution.

Comment: Hi, did you found the solution? If so, it will be great to post self answer :) 
I'm facing with the same trouble.

Comment: Hi @user1802474, unfortunately I couldn't get any solution yet.

Comment: One possible solution I'm thinking about - is to take manual control over it. When bandwith becomes low (determine it by RTCstats) we should manually degrade video quality by resolution or fps constraints.

Comment: @user1802474, looks like a good idea. Let me know if you get any success. I will try my side asap.